# 'SyntaxError: Identifier directly after number' when string starts with number

Tags: node.js, webpack

I want to have the current commit hash on both my dev and prod env which can getable with `/version` path.

My webpack config:

```
//webpack.config.js

...
const commitHash = require('child_process').execSync('cd .. && git rev-parse --short HEAD', {encoding: 'utf8'}).trim();

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'COMMIT_HASH': commitHash,
    })
  ]
};
```

My nodejs server:

```
//server.js

...
fastify.get('/version', function (request, reply) {
  const version = process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev" ? 
    require('child_process').execSync('cd .. && git rev-parse --short HEAD', {encoding: 'utf8'}).trim() : COMMIT_HASH;
  reply.send(version);
})
...
```

And my problem is that when i build it with webpack i get the `SyntaxError: Identifier directly after number` and

```
server.js from Terser plugin
Invalid syntax: 3511a4a [webpack://./server.js:214,104]
```

where the line 214 is the `require('child_process')...`.

BUT

if i change the webpack config to `const commitHash = 'a3511a4a';` everything is fine and the build is successful. And if i change it to `const commitHash = '3511a4a';` the error comes again.

Webpack version is `5.64.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value given to it must include actual quotes inside of the string itself. Typically, this is done either with alternate quotes, such as '"3511a4a"', or by using JSON.stringify('3511a4a').

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: Omg! Never ever figure it out that this cause it. Thanks!